# Preventing Window Size Detection on Opera

Tags: opera

I'm currently using Opera browser and I want to prevent websites from knowing what's the size of my window.  Is there a way to do it? if not directly perhaps through User Javascript folder?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: trying to surf with multiple cascading windows and some websites don't like it for some reason, so they block it (they also have blocking of Ad Block, so I'm guessing it's a similar reason)

Comment: Turn off Javascript.

Comment: I would like other javascript functions to keep on working.. so that would not work

Answer (score 1):

This will only be possible by blocking some (or maybe all) script activity on the target site. 
I found this Opera extension https://addons.opera.com/de/addons/extensions/details/notscripts/1.1.0/?display=en which may do the trick.

Comment: that far I know, I thought there might be a way to send a false result to scripts that try to detect my window size

Comment: In general, this is possible. You will need to do some reverse engineering to find out when and how the script detects your window size and some programming to catch the request and return false data. You may want to read the documentation for programming opera add-on's, that may help.